# wordpress contact form7 conditional emailing

Tags: wordpress

> In WORD PRESS, How to use contact form 7 for conditional emailing , for example when the user fills the form and submits, then the query form and email should be sent to the department selected by user in drop down in the form !

Answer (score 0):

For Conditional Emailing You can use below code :

```
[select your-recipient "CEO|ceo@example.com"
                    "Sales|sales@example.com"
                    "Support|support@example.com"]
```

For More details you can visit below links : 
**1)** http://contactform7.com/selectable-recipient-with-pipes/

**2)** https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-contact-form-7-specify-email-address-mail-is-sent-to?replies=2#post-985356